# Protractor retry a function after wait conditions fails

Tags: angular, async-await, protractor, timeout

I have some flaky tests that I'm trying to fix. 
Protractor: 5.3.2
Angular 6

This is what I'm trying to do:

1. Load a page (data should loaded from db)
2. Wait until conditions are met: Data is loaded & loading spinner is invisible
3. If conditions are not met retry, reload the page

This is my code:

```
  async navigate(): Promise<void> {
    return await browser.get('/', 10000).then(async () => {
      return await this.waitForDataToLoad(10000);
    });
  }

  async waitForDataToLoad(timeOut?: number): Promise<any> {
    let isSpinnerInVisible = ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(element(By.css("spinner")));
    let isWorkflowLoaded = ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element(By.css("employee-list ul li:first-child a")));
    return browser.wait( ExpectedConditions.and(isSpinnerInVisible, isWorkflowLoaded), timeOut, 'data was not loaded in the given timeout');
  }
```

I have couple of issues:

1 - My custom time out error message never get printed in the console, it only prints default error as:  - `Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL`

2- I tried adding retry function as below but seems like it doesn't work:

```
 async navigate(): Promise<void> {
    return await browser.get('/', 10000).then(async () => {
      return await this.waitForDataToLoad(10000);
    }, (err) => {
      console.log('Data was not loaded:', err.message);
      this.navigate(); // Re try 
    });
  }
```

Any idea how can I achieve this? I'm aware there are Protractor flake and Retry npm packages but they don't exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem as:

```
  navigate(): promise.Promise<any> {
return browser.get('/').then(async () => {
  let waitForCondition = this.waitForDataToLoad(10000)
    .then((found) => {
      return Promise.resolve(found);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      if (this.retryAttempts < 4) {
        console.log(`Retrying navigate, attempt: ${this.retryAttempts}.`);
        this.navigate();
      } else {
        console.log('Rejecting the promise after 3 attempts.');
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    });;
  this.retryAttempts++;
  return waitForCondition;
});
```

}

```
waitForDataToLoad(timeOut?: number): promise.Promise<{}> {
    let isSpinnerInVisible =  let isSpinnerInVisible = ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(element(By.css("spinner")));
    let isWorkflowLoaded = ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element(By.css("employee-list ul li:first-child a")));

    return browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.and(isSpinnerInVisible, isWorkflowLoaded), timeOut)
  }
```

Comment: Looks like you already figured out a solution. I usually use `setInterval` for this kind of stuff.  The interval will run until the correct condition is met and then you can tell it to exit. You can see a decent example [here](https://javascript.info/settimeout-setinterval#setinterval)